Docker build doesn't work on M1 mac but works perfectly fine in Mac Intel
Currently, I'm migrating all work from Macbook Intel to Macbook Pro Apple M1 Series chip
When I build a dockerfile on an Intel Macbook, it is a success. However, when I build the same dockerFile on M1 Mac I get this error.
docker build --no-cache . -t apache/airflow:2.3.3                                             
[+] Building 47.1s (10/11)                                                                                                             docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.98kB                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/apache/airflow:2.3.3-python3.8                                                                              0.6s
 => [auth] apache/airflow:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 189B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/apache/airflow:2.3.3-python3.8@sha256:c6a69cf649ad6cbe5e06154b3625c5c8c960c32e605fda3ae6f3b206b7f2b96e                 0.0s
 => [2/6] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [3/6] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential gcc g++ git awscli                                                                 42.1s
 => [4/6] RUN sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&     mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial &&     apt-get clean &&     apt-get update                      1.4s
 => ERROR [5/6] RUN python3 -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt     -c "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.3.3/cons  2.9s
------
 > [5/6] RUN python3 -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt     -c "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.3.3/constraints-source-providers-3.8.txt":
0.241 + python3 -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.3.3/constraints-source-providers-3.8.txt
1.535 Collecting apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.4.0
1.656   Downloading apache_airflow_providers_common_sql-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
1.672 Requirement already satisfied: apache-airflow-providers-amazon==4.0.0 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (4.0.0)
1.748 Collecting apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==3.2.0
1.777   Downloading apache_airflow_providers_snowflake-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
1.781 Requirement already satisfied: apache-airflow-providers-mysql==3.0.0 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.0.0)
1.838 Collecting apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql==3.2.0
1.863   Downloading apache_airflow_providers_microsoft_mssql-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
1.868 Requirement already satisfied: apache-airflow-providers-odbc==3.0.0 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (3.0.0)
1.930 Collecting apache-airflow-providers-mongo==3.0.0
1.954   Downloading apache_airflow_providers_mongo-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
1.958 Requirement already satisfied: apache-airflow-providers-slack==5.0.0 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (5.0.0)
2.015 Collecting apache-airflow-providers-opsgenie==5.0.0
2.039   Downloading apache_airflow_providers_opsgenie-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
2.186 Collecting apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes==5.3.0
2.214   Downloading apache_airflow_providers_cncf_kubernetes-5.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
2.227 Requirement already satisfied: boto3==1.24.23 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (1.24.23)
2.228 Requirement already satisfied: botocore==1.27.23 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (1.27.23)
2.274 Collecting openpyxl==3.0.9
2.303   Downloading openpyxl-3.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (242 kB)
2.341 Requirement already satisfied: pandas==1.4.3 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 14)) (1.4.3)
2.341 Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary==2.9.3 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) (2.9.3)
2.342 Requirement already satisfied: kubernetes==23.6.0 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 16)) (23.6.0)
2.343 Requirement already satisfied: requests==2.28.0 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 17)) (2.28.0)
2.387 Collecting snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.3.4
2.416   Downloading snowflake_sqlalchemy-1.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
2.502 Collecting mysql-connector-python==8.0.29
2.524   Downloading mysql_connector_python-8.0.29-py2.py3-none-any.whl (342 kB)
2.571 Collecting mysqlclient==2.1.1
2.594   Downloading mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
2.607   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
2.867   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
2.869   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
2.869
2.869   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
2.869   │ exit code: 1
2.869   ╰─> [16 lines of output]
2.869       /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: Permission denied
2.869       /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: Permission denied
2.869       /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: Permission denied
2.869       Traceback (most recent call last):
2.869         File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
2.869         File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
2.869         File "/tmp/pip-install-wk9zky_3/mysqlclient_ca5924e783e548669d6fe900a78e8727/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
2.869           metadata, options = get_config()
2.869         File "/tmp/pip-install-wk9zky_3/mysqlclient_ca5924e783e548669d6fe900a78e8727/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
2.869           libs = mysql_config("libs")
2.869         File "/tmp/pip-install-wk9zky_3/mysqlclient_ca5924e783e548669d6fe900a78e8727/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
2.869           raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
2.869       OSError: mysql_config not found
2.869       mysql_config --version
2.869       mariadb_config --version
2.869       mysql_config --libs
2.869       [end of output]
2.869
2.869   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
2.870 error: metadata-generation-failed
2.870
2.870 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
2.870 ╰─> See above for output.
2.870
2.870 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
2.870 hint: See above for details.
------
Dockerfile:35
--------------------
  34 |     USER airflow
  35 | >>> RUN python3 -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt \
  36 | >>>     -c "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-source-providers-${PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION}.txt"
  37 |     RUN python3 -m pip install dbt-core dbt-snowflake snowflake-connector-python typing-extensions==4.6.3
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -o pipefail -e -u -x -c python3 -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt     -c \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-source-providers-${PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION}.txt\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/icmt9k7rj6v2k9qhtzpgbqf95

How do we solve this problem?
My requirements.txt and dockerFile are below
# Global Docker Build arguments
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.3.3
ARG PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION=3.8
FROM apache/airflow:${AIRFLOW_VERSION}-python${PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION}
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-e", "-u", "-x", "-c"]
USER 0
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential gcc g++ git awscli
RUN sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get update

ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION
ARG PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8 \
    LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8 \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 \
    PIP_PROGRESS_BAR="off" \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=1

USER airflow
RUN python3 -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt \
    -c "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-source-providers-${PYTHON_RUNTIME_VERSION}.txt"
RUN python3 -m pip install dbt-core dbt-snowflake snowflake-connector-python typing-extensions==4.6.3

Requirements.txt
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.4.0
apache-airflow-providers-amazon==4.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==3.2.0
apache-airflow-providers-mysql==3.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql==3.2.0
apache-airflow-providers-odbc==3.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-mongo==3.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-slack==5.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-opsgenie==5.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes==5.3.0
boto3==1.24.23
botocore==1.27.23
openpyxl==3.0.9
pandas==1.4.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3 
kubernetes==23.6.0
requests==2.28.0
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.3.4
mysql-connector-python==8.0.29
mysqlclient==2.1.1
opsgenie-sdk==2.1.5
pymssql==2.2.5
pymongo==3.12.3
timeago
billiard==3.6.4.0
ntlm-auth==1.5.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
requests-ntlm==1.1.0
apache-airflow-providers-ftp
apache-airflow-providers-http
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite
apache-airflow-providers-postgres
apache-airflow-providers-ssh
jq
gspread==5.11.3
oauth2client==4.1.3


I suspect mysqlclient==2.1.1 is the culprit, because I just ran pip install mysqlclient==2.1.1 on my MacBook Pro (with an M1 chip, by the way) and I get the exact same error you're getting in your output. Have a look here for a possible solution.

Thanks a lot , from the solution link you provided , which is the right solution to update in the dockerFile ?

You have to install MySQL/MariaDB dev headers for successfully build mysqlclient. This package prebuilt and preinstalled in the regular (non-slim) official Airflow Docker Image for ARM (experimental) since Airflow 2.6
You might want to customise your docker image from the official one, see:  Building the image: Customizing the image
If you want to build your own image from the scratch, I would recommend to look on Dockerfile in Apache Airlflow repo, you also could have a look which system dependency installed in addition for build mysqlclient into the scripts/docker/install_mysql.sh. And as far as I remember you need to install pkgconf via apt for build recent versions of mysqlclient
